# Merging two JSON files based on common key value pair using jq

Tags: shell, jq, jenkins-groovy

I have 2 JSON files with the following structure

File1.json

```
{
  "Plugins": [
               {
                 "Name": "Plugin A",
                 "Installation": [
                  {
                    "Version": "1.0",
                    "Server" : "abc"
                  }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "Name": "Plugin B",
                  "Installation": [
                   {
                     "Version": "2.0",
                     "Server" : "abc"
                   }
                   ]
               },
               {
                  "Name": "Plugin C",
                  "Installation": [
                   {
                     "Version": "2.0",
                     "Server" : "abc"
                   }
                   ]
               }
   ]
}
```

File2.json

```
{
  "Plugins": [
               {
                 "Name": "Plugin A",
                 "Installation": [
                  {
                    "Version": "1.1",
                    "Server" : "xyz"
                  }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "Name": "Plugin B",
                  "Installation": [
                   {
                     "Version": "2.0",
                     "Server" : "xyz"
                   }
                   ]
                },
   ]
}
```

I want to merge them and get the output like this

```
{
  "Plugins": [
               {
                 "Name": "Plugin A",
                 "Installation": [
                  {
                    "Version": "1.0",
                    "Server" : "abc"
                  },
                  {
                    "Version": "1.1",
                    "Server" : "xyz"
                  }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "Name": "Plugin B",
                  "Installation": [
                   {
                     "Version": "2.0",
                     "Server" : "abc"
                   },
                   {
                     "Version": "2.0",
                     "Server" : "xyz"
                   }
                   ]
               },
               {
                  "Name": "Plugin C",
                  "Installation": [
                   {
                     "Version": "2.0",
                     "Server" : "abc"
                   }
                   ]
               }
   ]
}
```

The two JSON files have exactly the same structure but only differ in terms of the content in the files.
I am mainly looking at using **jq** utility. Shell or jenkins-groovy scripts would be fine as well. 
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your example leaves one thing ambiguous: When both files have a plugin with different versions, should it always prefer the left one, or always prefer the smallest version number, or what? Please elaborate on why `{"Version":"1.0",...}` is picked for `"Plugin A"`.

Comment: The output has both the plugin versions under Installation array. The "Name" is the common key

Comment: The "Server" key will always be different between the files. The "Version" key might be same or different, but the output should contain content from both files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
def mergePlugin($plugin):
  if .[$plugin.Name]
  then .[$plugin.Name].Installation += $plugin.Installation
  else .[$plugin.Name] = $plugin
  end;

{
  "Plugins": (
    map(.Plugins)
    | add
    | reduce .[] as $plugin ({}; mergePlugin($plugin))
    | to_entries | map(.value)
  )
}
```

Running this:

```
jq -s -f mergePlugins.jq File*.json
```

Command-ine arguments explained:

> `--slurp` / `-s`: Instead of running the filter for each JSON object in  the  input, read the entire input stream into a large array and run the filter just once.
>
> `-f filename` / `--from-file filename`: Read  filter  from  the file rather than from a command line, like awk´s -f option. You can also use ´#´ to make comments.

[This jqplay snippet](https://jqplay.org/s/mrpoCZUAdh) simulates `-s` by providing a list of objects as input instead of a multiple of objects.

Here's how the solution works: `jq -s '.' File*.json` provides a list of `{"Plugins": [...]}` objects. Being interested in the `[...]` part, `jq -s 'map(.Plugins)' File*.json` provides this list of lists (one for each file):

```
[
  [
    {
      "Name": "Plugin A",
      ...
    },
    {
      "Name": "Plugin B",
      ...
    },
    {
      "Name": "Plugin C",
      ...
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "Name": "Plugin A",
      ...
    },
    {
      "Name": "Plugin B",
      ...
    }
  ]
]
```

We can collapse one layer of nested lists using `jq -s 'map(.Plugins) | add' File*.json`:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Plugin A",
    ...
  },
  {
    "Name": "Plugin B",
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

For the next part, since I want all `"Name": "Plugin X"` to be merged with one another, I figure a dictionary/object with the key being `"Plugin X"` will be a good data structure, since then for each plugin, I can do a constant-time lookup if I encountered it before or not.

I build this dictionary using [`reduce`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Reduce):

```
reduce .[] as $plugin ({}; ...some expression using '.' and '$plugin'...)
```

The `{}` is the initial value of this object, `$plugin` is each `{"Name": "Plugin X", "Installation": [...]}` value, and `.` is the intermediate dictionary/object containing keys that are `"Plugin X"` and values being `$plugin`-like objects.

Since the if-then-else gets a little long, I'm moving this into a helper filter, `mergePlugin`. This filter kind of takes two things: `.` and `$plugin`.

This produces:

```
{
  "Plugin A": {
    "Name": "Plugin A",
    "Installation": [
      {
        "Version": "1.0",
        "Server": "abc"
      },
      {
        "Version": "1.1",
        "Server": "xyz"
      }
    ]
  },
...
}
```

which is almost the final result, except there's an unnecessary `{"Plugin A": {...}}` wrapper that can now be scrapped, and there's a missing `{"Plugins": [...]}` wrapper that needs to be added back.

Ideas for improvement:

- I'm pretty sure you can do something smarter than

  ````
  ```
  {
    "Plugins": (
      ... | to_entries | map(.value)
    )
  }
  ```
  ````

  for this last part, but it does the job.
- I also think that the actual merging can be done shorter than the if-then-else.